# How to add a new attribute to a torch_geometric.data Data object element?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to extend the elements of a `TUDataset` dataset.
In particular, I have a dataset obtained via

`dataset = TUDataset("PROTEIN", name=PROTEIN, use_node_attr=True)`

I want to add a new vector-like feature to every entry of the dataset.

```
for i, current_g in enumerate(dataset):

    nxgraph = nx.to_numpy_array(torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(current_g) )
    feature = do_something(nxgraph)
    dataset[i].new_feature = feature
```

However, this code doesn't seem to work. As you can verify yourself, it's not possible to add attributes to an element of `dataset`.

```
In [80]: dataset[2].test = 1

In [81]: dataset[2].test
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/workspace/grouptheoretical/new-experiments/HGP-SL-myfork/main.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dataset[2].test

AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'test'

In [82]: dataset[2].__setattr__('test', 1)

In [83]: dataset[2].test
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/workspace/grouptheoretical/new-experiments/HGP-SL-myfork/main.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dataset[2].test

AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'test'
```

An element in `dataset` is a `Data` from `torch_geometric.data Data`.

I can create a new `Data` element with all the features I want by using:

```
tmp=dataset[i].to_dict()
tmp['new_feature'] = feature
new_dataset[i]=torch_geometric.data.Data.from_dict(tmp)
```

However, I don't know how to create a `TUDataset` dataset (Or the partent class of it) from a list of `Data` elements. Do you know how?

Any idea on how to solve this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One elegant way to reach your goal is to define your transformation.

```
from torch_geometric.transforms import BaseTransform

class Add_Node_Feature(BaseTransform):
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.paramters= paramters  # parameters you need
    def __call__(self, data: Data) -> Data:
        node_feature = data.x
        data.x = do_something(node_feature)
        return data
```

Then, you can apply this transformation when loading the dataset. This way, the dataset is modified, and new features will be added.

```
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
dataset = TUDataset("PROTEIN", name=PROTEIN, use_node_attr=True)
dataset.transform = T.Compose([Add_Node_Feature()])
```

Comment: i haven't tried this, but seems the right way of proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very easy. In most of the cases you just need a list (and `DataLoader` works with lists just fine):

`dataset = [change_element(element) for element in dataset]`

where change_element returns a new `Data` element as described in the question.