# How to change the value of an attribute of a torch_geometric.data Data object element?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to change the value of an attribute of a torch_geometric.data Data object element like this:

```
    a = train_data[0]  # Data(edge_index=[2, 267], y=[1], x=[33, 401], num_nodes=33)
    print(train_data[0].num_nodes) # 33
    train_data[0].num_nodes = 777
    print(train_data[0].num_nodes) # 33
```

It didn't work. *num_nodes* didn't change. *train_data* is a customized graph datasets composed of lots of subgraphs and *train_data[0]* is one of them.

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

And if I want change *data[i].edge_index* and *data[i].x*, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In a torch_geometric.data Data object, `num_nodes` is a type of property that is calculated according to the size of `x`. For example, in your graph `x`=[**33**, 401], and `num_nodes` is naturely 33.

You can change `data.x` and `data.edge_index` by assigning values as you show, but this is not efficient and often won't work if your graph dataset reads from a local file.
I suggest you define and apply your `torch_geometric.transforms` to modify the original graph. There is a detailed answer here:

[How to add a new attribute to a torch_geometric.data Data object element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77369606/how-to-add-a-new-attribute-to-a-torch-geometric-data-data-object-element/77523155#77523155)